# button text not shown when the enable is false

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell that contains three buttons, I want to make these buttons as **not** enabled, but I also want to choose dynamically which one of them is selected.

I did that but my problem is that when I make the button as not enabled, the text doesnt' show

look this is what it looks like when the button is not enabled

[image]

this is what it looks like when the button is enabled (this is the correct way, but in this case i can click on the buttons, which I dont want)

[image]

this is my code

```
 for (index, button) in [cell.firstTimeOption, cell.secondTimeOption, cell.thirdTimeOption].enumerate() {

            if oneResponse.timeOptions.count > index {
                button.setTitle(oneResponse.timeOptions[index], forState: .Selected)
                button.setTitle(oneResponse.timeOptions[index], forState: .Normal)
                button.enabled = false
                if index == oneResponse.selectedOptionIndex {
                    button.selected = true
                }else {
                    button.selected = false
                }

                button.hidden = false
            } else {
                button.hidden = true
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be mistaken as to how you want your button to behave, but from what I took of what you want shouldn't you not be using:

```
button.hidden = true;
```

As this will remove the button from the view entirely, which sure disables it, but it also makes it disapear!

I believe you want:

```
button.userInteractionEnabled = true;
```

Or

```
button.userInteractionEnabled = false;
```

Accordingly.